# Android: How to catch spam email addresses after bot has signed in

Tags: android, spam-prevention, android-security

I can get email addresses of users in my app, and sometimes they comes with addresses like this: `angiewelch.99218@gmail.com`. My app provides some service, it's free for users now, but it's paid for me. So I guess it's a good idea to restrict spammed users of using the app paid options. What is the best way to catch spammed email addresses? Thanks.

Comment: did you use some sort of activation code when they register into your app?

Comment: By spam do you mean email addresses that don't exist? If that's the case you can use Firebase authentication for verifying email with OTP. It is free for some daily limit, but for more requests you will have to buy plan.

Comment: @Lino I have fast login using Google account. But the question is about using some lib to check if email address looks spammy